# How to handle Dictionary with missing key

Tags: ios

I have a dictionary with info (name, age etc) that I need to use in a tableView to populate a profile viewController.

My problem is that I dont know if the user for example has added his name, and therefore if there is a key = "name".
So when I index into the dictionary

```
print("firstname: \(userDocument["name"]!["first"] as! String)")
```

the app crash if the key does not exist..

**How can I avoid this?  should I use if let on all the keys ?**

I tried:

```
print("firstname: \(userDocument["name"]?["first"] as? String)")
```

but then I get the Optional(Elon Musk) and I dont what that as the label.text.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: i recommend to you , normalize your data before populate in tableview,any way you can check your key is exist or no after that you can read value of this key ?

Comment: @mohamad-farhand Yes, but how should I do that ?

Comment: you can check with :  if([dic objectforkey:"yourKey"]

Comment: Consider to design the model to pass all keys, but use an empty string for `no value`. That avoids a lot of optional binding overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var defaultName = "unspecified"
print("firstname: \((userDocument["name"]?["first"] as? String) ?? defaultName)")
```

This checks whether `(userDocument["name"]?["first"] as? String)` contains a value, and provides a substitute (`defaultName`) if it doesn't.  You can change the substitute text to whatever you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The ! means "please crash if it doesn't exist". So what you wrote is crashing *because you told the compiler to make it crash*. If you don't want the crash, don't do that.

Use ? in the right places which will give you an optional value. Then you can use optional ?? defaultValue to substitute a value in case the optional is nil, or do whatever is appropriate if the value isn't there.